# GitHub-API - get latest api version return "Not Found"

Tags: github, github-api

I am using GitHub-API to get the latest version for my used API's e.g. "Parse-SDK-Android" & "parse-server".

Querying "https://api.github.com/repos/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/releases/latest"
returns the wright JSON data.

Querying "https://api.github.com/repos/ParsePlatform/parse-server/releases/latest"
returns JSON "message": "Not Found".

According to the docs it could be an authentication problem.

So i have run the queries using a generated access_token and it's still give me  "message": "Not Found", so it's not an authentication problem.

As i see parse-server repository isn't private.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your request.

```
GET: https://api.github.com/repos/ParsePlatform/parse-server/releases
```

Gives you an empty result:

```
[]
```

They just don't have [releases created](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) for this repository. Compare it with

```
GET: https://api.github.com/repos/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/releases
```

As a workaround you can use

```
GET: https://api.github.com/repos/ParsePlatform/parse-server/tags
```

And look at the latest tag.

```
    {
       "name": "2.1.2",
       "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ParsePlatform/parse-server/zipball/2.1.2",
       "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ParsePlatform/parse-server/tarball/2.1.2",
       "commit": {
          "sha": "01f4bcc3e3f259f2e6e763584e764ed036a657fe",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ParsePlatform/parse-server/commits/01f4bcc3e3f259f2e6e763584e764ed036a657fe"
       }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue check:

1. The *Repository* is **public**
2. The *Release* is **public** as well
3. No mistakes in user's or repo's names
4. Don't put a trailing slash: USE `/releases`, NOT `/releases/`

If everything is fine, try to request the following link to get a JSON response:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/releases
```